# How to tell where Powershell events handlers are invoked from?

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

I have a PowerShell script which creates a WinForms GUI. On the main form there are a large number of buttons (PushButtons), each with a different name/text. **I'm trying to find a way to iteratively give each button a click event listener that writes the respective button's name to the console.** The problem is that whenever the function is called (the function I originally passed into "$button.Add_Click({function})"), I'm not quite sure how to refer/get access to the name of the button from within this function. It's almost as if I'm no longer in the scope of the button being clicked, so I don't really have access to the button anymore.

Example:

```
$ButtonArray.ForEach({
    $_.Add_Click({ Say-Name })
})

function Say-Name() {
    Write-Host # How do I access the button's properties?
}
```

In the example above, I'm stuck at the Write-Host part. I've tried using `$_` to refer to the button, but it turns out that `$_` actually refers to a `System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs` object. I've tried passing parameters in through the `Add_Click` script block, but that doesn't work because once I've entered the script block, I don't have access to any external information. **How do I let my function know which button invoked it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script blocks passed to `.add_<event>()` methods (the equivalent of `.<event> +=` in C#) act as [`EventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler-1) delegates and are therefore passed two arguments:

- the sender (the originating object): in your case, the `[System.Windows.Forms.Button]` that triggered the event.
- event arguments (details): an instance of a type derived from `[System.EventArgs]` or, for events without arguments, the `[System.EventArgs]::Empty` singleton; this information is also *implicitly* reflected in automatic variable `$_`.

Therefore, to get the name of the button control at hand, *declare* these parameters, so you can access them:

```
$_.add_Click({ 
  param($sender, $eventArgs)
  $buttonName = $sender.Name
})
```

Comment: it is possible to know the event name in the scriptblock called ?

Comment: @Alban, not directly, as far as I know. If you want to share a script block for multiple events (is that the intent?), you may be able to at least narrow down which event  you're dealing with, by looking at the  .NET type name of the `$eventArgs` argument. However, not can multiple events share the same event-arguments type, some events have _no_ event arguments. If this doesn't help, I suggest you ask a new question, in which you can flesh out your use case.

Comment: i ask a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872464/how-to-know-the-name-of-the-winform-event-that-triggers-the-scriptblock