# How to know the name of the Winform.Event that triggers the scriptblock?

Tags: multithreading, forms, powershell, winforms

I construct a PSWinForm-Builder,

Each event has a Scriptblock in a list of $ThreadEventHandler they are named `Control.Name - Event.Name`.

```
$ThreadEventHandler["Button1-Click"] = [ScriptBlock]{...}
```

when i add simple scriptblock on `controler.event` it is ok.

But for slower scriptblock i want the event use **Start-ThreadJob** whit scriptblock named `Control.Name - Event.Name`, in event I use `$this.Name` for `Control.Name` and i haven't acces to `$ThisEvent.Name`

```
$Form.Button1.Add_Click({
    Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock $ThreadEventHandler["$($this.Name)-$($ThisEvent.Name)"]
})
```

Have you an idea for transmit `$ThisEvent.Name` in Event ScriptBlock ?

[My Full code on GitHub](https://github.com/sctfic/PSWinForm-Builder/blob/main/PSWinForm-Builder.psm1#L183)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link to your source code, I suggest creating your script block from an expandable (here-)string via `[scriptblock]::Create()` instead of using a script-block *literal* (`{ ... }`), as that allows you to "bake" the value of the `$Evt` variable containing the event name into the script block; note how the variable references that should *not* be expanded (interpolated) up front have their `$` sigil escaped as `` `$ ``.

```
$Script:ControlHandler[$Name]."Add_$($Evt)"(
  [scriptblock]::Create(@"
    param(`$caller, `$e)
    Start-ThreadJob -Name "`$(`$this.Name)-$Evt" -ScriptBlock `$Script:ThreadEventHandler["`$(`$this.Name)-$Evt"].ScriptBlock
"@)
)
```